# Filter for records between two dates

Tags: apache-pig

I don't seem to see any keyword equivalent for MySQL 'BETWEEN' in Pig Latin.

What I want to do is filter for records between two specific dates. Any tips on how to do so in Pig Latin?

Answer (score 0):

To do so, using FILTER.

```
variable = FILTER variable_holding_table_data BY (GetYear(date_column)==year) AND (GetMonth(date_column)==month) AND (GetDay(date_column)=>date_day_start AND GetDay(date_column)<=date_day_end);

e.g. query = FILTER orders BY (GetYear(date)==2013) AND (GetMonth(date)==05) AND (GetDay(date)>=01 AND GetDay(date)<=31);
```

Resources:
[Pig Date Functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_pig/apache_pig_date_time_functions.htm)